# Where does the smartselect URLS belong?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to set op SmartSelect in my django project so I can chain dropdown menu's.
I do not understand how/where the urls belongs for the installation?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
)
```

[This](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) is what their official installation guide says. Though this is either and old version of Django or i'm doing something wrong as I have not seen any URLS file written this way before and VScode does not recognize it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path) and has been removed in [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0).
Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
use [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.

So you can implement this as:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    path('chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

That being said, if the documentation is that old, the project might no longer be "alive".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know of any other way to make dependent dropdown menu's?
I have a category dropdown selection which should populate another dropdown with products from said category.